# How can I allow github action execution for read only users?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to protect my execution server from actions workflows changes. Therefore i created the actions in dedicated repo and granted readonly permission for the collaborators.

The problem is that they now can not execute the workflow manually...

How can i solve that problem? I want that only DevOps will be able to change and create workflows but every developer will be allowed to run it.

Comment: Are you using `workflow_dispatch`? If yes, that can be triggered by an API call.

Comment: @Max  tried but then I need to share a token so the users who run it will have access to that token as well. am I right?

Comment: You would wanna store that token as a secret in GitHub, either at the repo or at the org level.